# Regular expression to match !WSⅡ%^ OR WSⅡ in a string in C#

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc

How do I match alpahbet with roman symbol following with regular expressions.

1. I have got #!WSⅡ%^ WSⅡ ancient data =>(should match both WSⅡ)
2. I have got #!WSⅡ%^ @#WSⅡ WSⅡ ancient data =>(should match 3 times)
3. I have got AbWSⅡ WSⅡRR WSⅡ ancient data =>(should match 1 time) (AbWSⅡ WSⅡRR should not match)

I am using the following regular expression.

**(?<![a-zA-Z0-9])(\bWSⅡ\b)(?=[a-zA-Z0-9]|)**

Which is working for my all the cases except the above.

**Note**: Ⅱ is not II

Please help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you mean `WSⅡ` instead of `Test` in the regex? Try `(?<![^\W_])WSⅡ(?![^\W_])`

Comment: @Wiktor tribiżew, yes WSⅡ

Comment: Then edit the post!

Comment: I've seen the exact question before, though I think it was marked as a duplicate because of your poor explanation of your problem. I can't tell what parts of your question are the inputs you expect. Can you describe them by providing code snippets in your question. eg `var input = "#!WSⅡ%^ WSⅡ";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```cs
(?<![^\W_])WSⅡ(?![^\W_])
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C!%5B%5E%5CW_%5D%29WS%E2%85%A1%28%3F!%5B%5E%5CW_%5D%29&i=I%20have%20got%20%23!WS%E2%85%A1%25%5E%20WS%E2%85%A1%20ancient%20data%20%3D%3E%28should%20match%20both%20WS%E2%85%A1%29%0D%0AI%20have%20got%20%23!WS%E2%85%A1%25%5E%20%40%23WS%E2%85%A1%20WS%E2%85%A1%20ancient%20data%20%3D%3E%28should%20match%203%20times%29%0D%0AI%20have%20got%20AbWS%E2%85%A1%20WS%E2%85%A1RR%20WS%E2%85%A1%20ancient%20data%20%3D%3E%28should%20match%201%20time%29%20%28AbWS%E2%85%A1%20WS%E2%85%A1RR%20should%20not%20match%29).

The regex matches

- `(?<![^\W_])` - a negative lookbehind that matches a location that is not immediately preceded with a char other than a non-word and `_` char (so it basically requires start of string or a non-word char or `_` right before)
- `WSⅡ` - a `WSⅡ` word
- `(?![^\W_])` - a negative lookahead that matches a location that is not immediately followed with a char other than a non-word and `_` char (so it basically requires end of string or a non-word char or `_` right after).